# How do I select a web element that doesn't have any unique value using Capybara

Tags: css, xpath, capybara, ambiguous

I am trying to enter value to a textbox email that doesn't have any unique attribute value using Capybara.

How can I select an element without a unique class, label or attribute?

Comment: There has to be something unique or there wouldn’t be a way to submit the field correctly. Please add the HTML form to your question so we can see what you’re dealing with

Comment: Without something unique, you would have to find it relative to some other unique element.  This will not be resilient to changes in the future though.